# How do I add a click method to an href link in an unordered list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a menu of clickable items in an unordered list. Regardless what element I place I wrap with a list item nothing fires the click callback method I have provided.

Here I use an href elememt

```
trackDeleteButton = $('<a href="#">DELETE</a>')[0];
$(trackDeleteButton).click(function () {
    myself.browser.removeTrack(myself.track);
    igv.popover.hide();
});
```

// Create a list item wrapper and unorder list item

```
var acc = [],
    listItem = $('<li>')[0],
    unorderedList = $('<ul>')[0];

$(listItem).append(trackDeleteButton);
acc.push($(listItem).prop('outerHTML'));
```

// add additional random items for grins

```
["foxtrot", "bravo", "lima"].forEach(function (item, i, items) {
    acc.push('<li>' + item + " " + i + '</li>');
});

$(unorderedList).append( acc.join('') );
```

// Pass the unoderlist to a method to host it in a div.

```
igv.popover.presentTrackMenu(e.pageX, e.pageY, $(unorderedList));
```

The **click** method is **never** called. Why? What is the work around.

Comment: Could you submit your html?

Comment: if you are registering the listener before inserting the items into the dom it won't fire with .click() `.on('click', 'selector', callback)` would work for you. Also, `trackDeleteButton` is already wrapped with jquery so you should be able to call `trackDeleteButton.on()`

Comment: Why are you getting the underlying dom element from your jQuery objects only to rewrap it in jQuery? ie `listItem = $('<li>')[0] ... $(listItem).append...`

Comment: Shan, not sure you are correct about click(). My code registers a click handler with an element. When the element is clicked the method fires. No need to use on(...). The wrapping/unwrapping is unnecessary (I am an iOS dev still new to JS/jQuery) but not relevant to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behavior, because your script loaded before elem, use on method to attach event

```
$("parent").on("click", "your item selector", someFunction);

someFunction(e){

   e.preventDefault() || return false - to prevent normal behavior of a elem
}
```

Comment: SmileOff actually all my JS is loaded via $(document).ready(function () { ... }.

Comment: its different things, after DOM loading you insert extra html and try to bind events to it, but this html wasn't loaded, so use event delegation to achive what you want...

Comment: Ok, let me see if I got this. The line of code that appears to assign the click method to trackDeleteButton does not actually happen because trackDeleteButton is not inserted in the DOM yet. Correct?

Comment: SmileOff, for context, DOM insertion happens in the function igv.popover.presentTrackMenu(...). If you give a bit more description of you solution I will give your this one.

Comment: Sry, I don't have pc now to give you more complex answer, but you got this right, just bind your event to already existing elem which wasn't generated with your script, try to read event delegation in query official documentation, there is only one page with examples, good luck

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you'd like to do, but the following code shows how to add a click handler to links in a li-element dynamically:

```js
$(function() {
    var elNo = 0;
    var $list = $('#dynamicList');
    
    $('#addElement').on('click', function(){
        $newLi = $('<li/>', {text: elNo} ).appendTo($list);
        $delLink = $('<a/>', {href: '#', text: ' delete', class: 'remove'}).appendTo($newLi);
        $delLink.on('click', function(){
            $(this).closest('li').remove();
        });
        
        elNo++;
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addElement">Add list item</button>
<ul id='dynamicList'>
</ul>
```